# Parallel processing from MySQL bin log

Tags: mysql, database, mysqlbinlog

We are currently doing bin log streaming from Mysql to other dbs down the line.

The problem we are facing is the sequence of events, we are not able to do parallel processing i.e the events written in bin log are ordered by time and we cannot easily do parallel query insert in the downstream db and inserting on a single connection is very slow since the downstream db is a columnar db.

Is there anyway we can read the events in a way that we can effectively parallelise the persistence in the secondary db.

Answer (score 0):

As binlog contain stream of events instead of snapshot of data at that instant,.. we can't frame state out by do ing parallel event processing.

If you are sure that, your tables does not have dependency on one another, then run N(Assuming you have N tables) binlog processors parallel with filter condition on each table name.

Another way is to group multiple dependent tables into sets and have filter condition to process specific set of tables by on single binlog process. You can have as many sets as you can.